# Sudoku pairs diagonal corners

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Is it correct to deduct that the [4,8] (blue) pairs in diagonal corners, project [4,8] on the opposite (green) corners, such that the other values (1 and 6) could be eliminated?

(*) I'm not sure if this is XY, something else, or if I just invented something because I find it convenient.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not correct to eliminate the 1 and 6 from the greens here. In fact, if both blue and green were [4,8], how would you ever know which one is the 4 and which is the 8? The puzzle wouldn't even have a single correct answer.

Comment: By eliminating, I'm left with a single 1 (below the green [1,4,8]), which, according to the puzzle, is the correct answer (I stopped there). Do I understand correctly, that four corners of a rectangle with the exact same pair is an absolute illegal state in normal sudoku?

Comment: I don't know if it's illegal per se, but definitely a sign of a broken puzzle. If everything else is correct and you end up with a rectangle like that in the grid, you know the puzzle either has no correct solution or it has more than one. (Note that this isn't necessarily true in variant sudokus, where they may be other information available to distinguish between the two possible solutions.)

Comment: @AVIDeveloper it is not illegal according to sudoku rules.  But there is the unwritten rule that a sudoku should have a unique solution.  That is what is expected, and that is how it is done.  Now such a rectangle would imply there are either zero or multiple solutions.  In a normal sudoku there are no multiple solutions, so this situation indicates this is not part of a solution.  In short, it is not illegal, but you can treat it as such.

Comment: In this case it does lead to contradictions in the puzzle. That is, dropping the 1 and 6 as you suggest leads to a situation with no solution.